# change the event trigger for only one field

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

i'm using this plug in to validate a form
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

I've got 3 fields, and the first one is username. 
I want to check the availability of the username only on focusout (not keyup...) using 'remote'.
The rest of the fields validate as usual.

Can I do that? How can change the event trigger for only one field?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#yourform').validate({
//...Your existing validation logic...
onfocusout: function(element){
    if($(element).attr('id') == 'usernameID'){
        //add your remote logic somewhere here
        //or just:
        $(element).valid(); 
    }
}
```

});